# Passing a string when calling the constructor of a class in PHP

Tags: php, class

I'm starting learning classes in PHP. I coded that:

```
class User {
    function getFbId($authtoken) {
        
    }
    function getFbFirstName ($authtoken) {
    
    }
}
```

What I want to do is something like that: `$user=new User($authtoken);` And pass the `$authtoken` to the class. It's possible to define that when starting the class. It's possible to retrieve that value inside a function of that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the variable passed in constructor throughout your class, you can create a class level variable like this:

```
class User {
    private $tokenID = NULL;

    function __construct($tokenID){
      // store token id in class level variable
      $this->tokenID  = $tokenID;
    }
    
    function someFun($authtoken) {    
      echo $this->tokenID;
    }
}
```

---

You need to create the [constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) in order to do that:

```
class User {

    function __construct($tokenID){
      // do something with $tokenID
    }
    
    function getFbId($authtoken) {    
      // code
    }
    
    function getFbFirstName ($authtoken) {
     // code
    }
}
```

**Note:**

If you are using **PHP4**, a constructor can be created with a function name same as that of class like:

```
class User {

    function User($tokenID){
      // do something with $tokenID
    }
    
    function getFbId($authtoken) {    
      // code
    }
    
    function getFbFirstName ($authtoken) {
     // code
    }
}
```

Now you can do something like:

```
$user = new User($authtoken);
```

Comment: One question, I don't have to run any code to get the $authtoken, just the user provides it. What code do I have to put there?

Comment: @Francesc: Then you can create the constructor but don't do anything with it :)

Comment: And then If I want to use the $tokenID in the other functions of the class, I only have to use that variable, is it right?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for contructors. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php
Or http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Programming-Basics/ObjectOriented-PHP-Constructors-and-Destructors/ for a walk through.